unabled to link all the pages
I have a wordpress powered website https://woonkyung.or.kr/
main page is loading
but all the liked page is not working
the error msg is
Not Found
The requested URL /woonkyungfoundation/ was not found on this server.

no one can't access to the ftp
why this is happening?

appears that you are encountering an error on your website due to a broken link. You can resolve this issue by following these steps:
1.Permalinks Settings: Verify and adjust your permalinks settings. Navigate to your WordPress dashboard, go to Settings > Permalinks, and ensure the settings are correct. You might need to re-save your permalink structure to refresh the links.
Check Page URLs: Review the URLs of the pages where the broken links are located. Ensure that the URLs are correct and that they correspond to the intended pages or content.

.htaccess File: Examine your website's .htaccess file. Sometimes, issues with permalinks and links can be caused by incorrect configurations in this file. You may need to regenerate or edit the .htaccess file to ensure proper redirection and link handling.

Check for Plugins/Themes Conflicts: Disable any recently installed plugins or themes that might be conflicting with your website's functionality. Temporarily switch to a default WordPress theme and deactivate plugins one by one to identify the source of the problem.



Thank You! The cause is the lack of capacity on the server. and .htaccess File was broken as well.
